# Definition of limit function

Tags: real-analysis

So consider the definition of a sequence of functions $f_n$ converging pointwise to $f$. Is this $f$ the same function as that defined by
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_k(x)?
$$
Isn't this one a SUM of values at a fixed point over all n, so this $f(x)$ is different ?I'm confused because beginning of Rudin CH7 he uses just $f(x)$

Comment: $f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$ is what you are looking for. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ does not necessarily converge.

Comment: $\sum f_n$ is not the limit of $f_n$'s. It is the sum of $f_n$'s. Rudin makes the distinction clear.

Comment: ok thank you, ^^ this is what I was looking for.